# MySQLSyntaxErrorException in query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
session.getAttribute('loginId')//giving 1

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='session.getAttribute('loginId')'");
```

or

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='session.getAttribute("loginId")'");
```

this is giving me sql Exception.

what wrong in my query? while-

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='1'");
```

is running fine.

I cant call this by storing loginId in String Object.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'loginId')'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the value returned from `getAttribute` rather than the literal value `session.getAttribute('loginId')`

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
            conn.prepareStatement("select * from interest where loginid=?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, session.getAttribute("loginId"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to concat the strings. Not inclusing the parameter in one string:

change to:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='"+session.getAttribute("loginId")+"'");
```

Or better use prepared statements. It prevents you for sql injection ans your query will be much more easier to read.

Comment: This is a introduces SQL injection and other problems (eg broken queries if they contain a single quote). Never concatenate values into an SQL query, always use parametrized queries.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Why the downvote. The answer is correct and i have pointed to prepared statements. But i do not want to write the code of prepared statement for the op. He/she has to lear it.

Comment: I downvoted because it shows the wrong (and as the last 20 years of security incidents caused by SQL injection have shown: dangerous) way of constructing SQL queries. Yes it solves the problem, but it solves it by introducing/reinforcing a dangerous solution.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So you think it is better to rewrite the code for OP with secure prepared statement without saying why like the other answer??

Comment: The other answer does both with _"Pass in the value returned from getAttribute rather than the literal value"_ (which - to me - is the same explanation as the first part of your answer). Granted, it could have explained it in more detail.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can not see the word sql injection or Why op should use prepared statements